# p5.js clear() function is not working properly in mobile and some browsers

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, p5.js

The HTML I've used is very simple which is given below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The sketch.js file is here:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}

function mousePressed() {
    clear();
}
```

I've followed exactly as in the example, but the clear is only working on some portion of it, not the whole canvas. I tried in different browsers on different PCs, some of it works good and some are not. Also all mobile chrome browsers have the same issue.

Below is a screenshot of how it looks in my browser:
[image: Clearing only a portion of the canvas]

Comment: what is the content of this `clear()` method? maybe the cleared size (somewhere inside the clear()) is less than 500?

Comment: @samAlvin here is an example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XYLYVE

Comment: @samAlvin Please note the [tag:p5.js] tag. The `clear()` function is provided by P5.js.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a known bug in p5.js that affects retina screens - https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/2846

There's already a fix for it - https://github.com/processing/p5.js/pull/2852 - but it hasn't been released at the time of writing.

In the interim using `$("canvas")[0].getContext('2d').clearRect(0,0,width,height);` instead of calling the `clear` method will have the desired effect. For example:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}

function mousePressed() {
    $("canvas")[0].getContext('2d').clearRect(0,0,width,height);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to call the `pixelDensity(1)` function:

```
function setup() {
    pixelDensity(1);
    createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
}

function mousePressed() {
    clear();
}
```

More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixelDensity):

> By default pixel density is set to match display density, call `pixelDensity(1)` to turn this off.